# Java Can not Cast from String to Integer_Sovled 

Tags: java, string, integer

```
HashMap<String, String> config = Feeds.config; 

String num =  config.get("NumOfFeeds");

System.out.println(num);

feedsAmount = ((Integer)num).intValue();

System.out.println(feedsAmount);
```

I've also tried `Integer.parseInt(num)` and `Integer.decode(num)` and `Integer.valueof(bu)`

Results as follows: 40

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:"40"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at fetch_RSS.<init>(fetch_RSS.java:40)
at testing.main(testing.java:27)
```

The problem was caused by different encoding from the txt file I'm reading from and the encoding in Elipse which is the macRoman by default.

Comment: what are you getting when u print num?

Comment: Please clarify what issue you have with Integer.parseInt() which should be what you are looking for.

Comment: You should probably tell us your output of `System.out.println(num);`.

Comment: I got the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "40" on String num = config.get("NumOfFeeds");

Comment: `Integer.parseInt("40")` does not throw `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

Comment: @AdithyaSurampudi I got 40 printed out and followed by the Exception

Comment: @UdoHeld I got 40 printed out and followed by the Exception

Comment: @Løkling I got 40 printed out and followed by the Exception

Comment: Wild guess: your input contains "4O" (capital o) and not "40" !? Try adding this to your code to verify that the string is what you expect (it cant be): 


System.out.print("Input is equal to 40:")
System.out.println("40".equals(num));

Comment: @Løkling You're right! The result of  System.out.println("40".equals(num)); is false. But it is 40...I tried several times in English input methods since sometimes I switched into  Chinese input method which is different. But it's still not working...

Comment: Are you sure that it's `"40"` and not `"４０"` or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of working is this:

```
String num = config.get("NumOfFeeds");
int feeds = Integer.parseInt(num);
```

This, only when you are sure that the String is representing a number the valid way.

```
-30         // correct
0           // correct
2000        // correct


"40"        // invalid
40          // valid

2.000       // invalid
2.000.000   // invalid
20,0        // invalid
2,000,000   // invalid
```

Comment: What if there is whitespace surrounding the number?

Comment: @Gabe: Invalid number as well (NumberFormatException precisely)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I've tried the parseInt(num), but it still throws the same exception.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy 40 has been printed out by "System.out.print(num)" and I used Integer.parseInt(num.trim()) but it still throws the same exception.

Comment: what does System.out.println(">" + num + "<"); produce?

Answer (score 1):

Your exception got raised in `Integer.java:458`.

Looking into the source code of `Integer` I see that some characters of your String "40" returned a negative value (most probably -1) for `Character.digit(s.charAt(i++), radix)` where `i` is iterating over String's characters and radix is 10.

This should not happen normally. But it happens when the String is "4o" and not "40" like @Løkling's wild guess in the comments.

You should debug here to see what really happens.

Comment: What is `s` in this case? Is it possible that OP could have some NLS setting that is specifying non-ASCII (maybe Arabic or Indic) digits so `s` doesn't contain ASCII digits?

Comment: @Gabe `s` is the String to parse. So it should be "40" when everything is like @user1058648 said. Debugging is here much more efficient since we cannot help here any further I think. With the data given we cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't cast from `String` to `Integer`. A `String` is not a `Integer`, and `Integer` is not a `String`.

You have to use `int i = Integer.parseInt(..)`. It works if the string is a properly formatted integer.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried this method but it still throws the same Exception....

Answer (score 0):

For a cast to succeed in Java, the reference being cast must point to an object that is actually an instance of the type being cast to.  A reference to `String` can't be cast to `Integer` because an object couldn't possibly be both things.

(This is somewhat unlike a cast in C, which is basically just saying, reinterpret the data stored here according to a different datatype.  It would still be incorrect in C to use casting as a method to convert a string representing a number to a numeric value.)

`Integer.parseInt` is what you are looking for here.  What problem are you having with it?

Answer (score 0):

Remember : In java, we can only cast between objects if they are EXPLICITLY of the same type !  In other languages , like python, we can do the casting you requested here, because those languages allow "duck typing".

You must use Integer.parseInt("1234"), to create an Integer object from a String.

Alternatively you could create an Object wrapper to your data :

```
class MyObject
{
    Object input; 
   public MyObject(Object input)
    {
         this.input=input;
    }

    public Integer getInt()
   {  
    return Integer.parseInt(input.toString());
   }
    public String getString()
   {
       return input.toString();
   }
}
```

This would be overkill for your simple problem, however :)